# Python arcpy recursive function problems

Tags: arcpy, cursor, algorithm

I'm trying to implement an algorithm using values from an arcpy module. Here is my equation written into code. I need for the initial value of the variables St and Yt to start off at zero. After the first time running through the loop I need the previous values of Yt,Qt,and St to be used for the next calculation. I havn't been able to figure out how to get to this to work.

```
V=0.416395
Dt= 0.5560694202
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile,mathlist)
for row in cursor:
    for i in range(1:len(mathlist))
        Yt = min(Dt,St)
        St = min(St+Qt-Yt,V)
        Qt = .82 * row[0] *row[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want those variables set to zero for each row in `shapefile`, your code should look like this:

```
V=0.416395
Dt= 0.5560694202
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile,mathlist)
for row in cursor:
    St = 0
    Yt = 0
    Qt = 0
    for i in range(1:len(mathlist))
        Yt = min(Dt,St)
        St = min(St+Qt-Yt,V)
        Qt = .82 * row[0] *row[i]
```

'Qt' also needs to be assigned a value before it can be used in an expression.